# How to authenticate and connect to Atlassian from apollo server?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, graphql, jira, apollo-server

I am trying to get data from my jira account but am unable to figure out where to start connecting Apollo server to Atlassian. I have an api token and my apollo server set up so I can query public api's. How do I authenticate my user with the Atlassian server in order to pull data from an account?

Comment: I think I can use JWTs

Comment: The JIRA docs has mentioned with two ways for authentication [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/jira/platform/rest-apis/).